# perform segue as full view from another view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, segue

I am trying to view another view from popover view controller as full view

```
@IBAction func AddCommentBTN(_ sender: Any) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "comment", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "comment" {
        let destination = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
        destination.comments = self.comments
        destination.myId = self.myId

    }
}
```

when I open it it loads the view as popover view, how to open it as full view

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using StoryBoards , here's how you do it

1)Go to the main.storyboard File and select the segue and got to its attributes inspector menu (select segue and press option + command + 5)
2)change the presentation option to fullScreen

And there you go you have fullScreen now , let me know how this went for you